# Is unaligned memory access allowed on iOS devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, arm

I'm currently working on app that loads blob of tightly packed data which contains different integer types (sized from char to int) that might not be properly aligned.

So, can I use simple `*(short*)ptr` or similar accesses to that data? Test on my iphone 5 shows no problem with that, but I'm not sure about all cases on all newer processors.

I did find some related informations, like this:

> ARMv6 and later, except some microcontroller versions, support unaligned accesses for half-word and single-word load/store instructions with some limitations, such as no guaranteed atomicity.

but in case of words it seems that on 32-bit and 64-bit ARMs word 32 and 64 bit accordingly, which would mean short requires proper alignment on 64-bit machine.

So, can I assume this is safe, or should I use some keywords like `__packed`?
Or should I rather avoid it completely and recreate my data so it always have proper alignment (or always use memmove when data is from external source and cannot by permanently modified)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ages ago that I tried it. And it worked, but every single access to unaligned memory caused a trap, which took considerable time. I'd suggest you measure how long it takes to add a million aligned shorts vs a million unaligned shorts. If you have a few hundred or thousand unaligned numbers, nothing to worry about.

__packed works reasonably fast. ARM has some clever instructions to do unaligned access with very few instructions. Again, I'd measure how long that takes. My experience with this is not current.

Comment: Well, the main thing I'm afraid of is that on some processor one of operations will be unsupported, but maybe I'm just excessively cautious.

No crashes on my device (on release settings I plan to use). As for speed, 32 and 64 bit stuff preferred 4 byte alignment, while 16 bit had some offset that were worse (always uneven, maybe some unlucky cache cases). Slow versions always run ~2x slower than fast ones.

Comment: From the ARMv6 doc (modern ARM of ARMv6+), the OP posts you can make unaligned accesses (if a CP15 is configured) and not trap.  You can not write 'atomically' to an unaligned access.  It may take multiple bus cycles where the CPU may be interrupted; half maybe in cache, etc.  For iOS, I would guess that they always allow the unaligned accesses as I don't think they have ARMv5 or lower devices?

Comment: It might be "allowed" but it will likely not be fast. Better to do byte reads and then construct your aligned data types with bit shifts or test to make sure that your compiler is generating the proper code to do that.